# only apply css style to first available class element within div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
     <p class="para">test</p>
     <p class="para">test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
     <p class="para">test3</p>
     <p class="para">test4</p>
     <p class="para">test5</p>
     <p class="para">test6</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
     <p class="para">test7</p>
     <p class="para">test8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then at the bottom of the page is some javascript:

```
<script>
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("para");
 var i;
 for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
   x[i].style.marginTop="120px";
 }
 </script>
```

The javascript loops through all of the `para` class elements and applies a `120px margin top`.

**The problem is i only want the first para within each `text div` to have a 120px margin top.**

So, the solution should have the `first para element within each text div` to have a margin top , which would include `test,test3,test7`

Comment: Do you have to do this in javascript? Unless there's a specfic reason, it would be better achieved using CSS instead of adding extra processing to the client-side.

Comment: @FluffyKitten i can try and get it to work with css

Comment: Can you use Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to using CSS, you could use `.text > .para:first-child` to set the `margin-top`. It is certainly more efficient than using Javascript.

```css
.text > .para:first-child {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
     <p class="para">test</p>
     <p class="para">test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
     <p class="para">test3</p>
     <p class="para">test4</p>
     <p class="para">test5</p>
     <p class="para">test6</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
     <p class="para">test7</p>
     <p class="para">test8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use the same selector with `document.querySelectorAll` to get the matching elements, and set the `margin-top` on them if you want.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.text > .para:first-child');

elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.style["margin-top"] = "120px";
});
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="para">test</p>
    <p class="para">test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="para">test3</p>
    <p class="para">test4</p>
    <p class="para">test5</p>
    <p class="para">test6</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="para">test7</p>
    <p class="para">test8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```